# Hibernate how to set all properties from a file except connection (datasource)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, datasource

We are using hibernate 5 and spring 4.

The bean which get `sessionFactory` is as

```
@Autowired
@Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {

   LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);

   sessionBuilder.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect");
   sessionBuilder.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
  .....
```

As there are lots of hibernate properties, I tried to put them in a property file, so all properties should be read from a file except the connection.

```
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource, Properties hibernateProperties) {

    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
    sessionBuilder.setProperties(hibernateProperties);
```

However when I run the code I get the error from hibernate `The application must supply JDBC connections` is not available. It seems that the pre-setted `dataSource` is ignored when I set the property file.

Is it possible to fix it?

As a workaround I use below, (which i not good):

```
LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);     

for(Entry<Object, Object> e : hibernateProperties.entrySet()) {
    sessionBuilder.setProperty(e.getKey().toString(), e.getValue().toString());
}
```

Comment: Just use `setProperties` instead of `setProperty`.

Comment: I have already used `setProperties`